# Deriving principal component out of cosine similarity

Tags: vectors, inner-products, projection, geometric-interpretation

Cosine similarity is defined as

$\frac{A\cdot B}{|A||B|}$

Now, if you multiply it by $|B|$, so that you have

$\frac{A \cdot B}{|A|}$,

what is the name for this?

Could this be considered a principal component?

and what kind of properties / interpretation would it have,

particularly in comparison to cosine distance or Euclidean distance?

Comment: What kind of objects are $A$ and $B$?  vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$?  What is $|A|$?

Comment: It is the scalar projection of $B$ onto $A.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, $A$ and $B$ are both vectors in $R^n$

Answer (score 2):

It's a length of the projection (multiplied by sign of $\cos$) of the vector $B$ on the vector $A$.